# Ensure fixed position div does not cover text

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm a bit new to CSS and was tinkering with this for quite a while and can't figure it out. I have an icon to play a video that I want fixed positioned at the bottom right corner. I have that working with pretty simple CSS:
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 16.5%;
     right: 8.25%;

But, if I resize the window and make it small, the icon will go over text. I was hoping to set it so that this will not happen, the icon will go off-screen.

I've tried a couple things, but it seems not possible with the right attribute. If I use left instead, it will work as I want it, but I want the icon to be as far right as possible so I guess I would need some sort of dynamic left position? This seems a bit overcomplicated and I was wondering if there is an easier solution.

Comment: try to set a `left` offset in pixel instead of right. Is your text always centered? is it left aligned? it could be useful see your actual page.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. But my text is always centered, so the left position would depend on the screen size. What I would need is something along the lines of 'min-left:960px' and other than that use right... if that existed.

Answer (score 1):

you could use mediaqueries

```
#button { position: fixed; bottom: 16.5%; }

/* browser width is less than 960px  */
@media screen and (min-width :0px) {
   #button { left : 961px }
}

/* browser width is at least 960px */
@media screen and (min-width : 960px) {
   #button { right: 8.25% }
}
```

of course set `960px` with other value if needed, it's just to give the idea: you can dinamycally re-position your button element depending on the screen width.

If you need to support IE 8 or lower you could use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick, hacky solution would be to set your video to a higher z-index than that of the button, so at least the button doesn't go above the video.

A JS solution would be as follows:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id='video'></div>
    <button>click</button>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#video { width: 500px; height: 350px; background: #d70; }
button { position: fixed; right: 10%; bottom: 10%; background: #ddd; font-size: 20px; padding: 10px; }
```

**JS** (via jQuery)

```
$(function () {

    //cache a few things
    var vid = $('#video'),
        button = $('button'),
        vid_dims = {w: vid.width(), h: vid.height()};

    //on resize, test to see if button is over video
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var button_coords = button.offset(),
            vid_coords = vid.offset(),
            positive_hit_test = button_coords.left > vid_coords.left && button_coords.left <  vid_coords.left + vid_dims.w && button_coords.top > vid_coords.top && button_coords.top <  vid_coords.top + vid_dims.h;

            //show or hide it accordingly
            button.css('visibility', positive_hit_test ? 'hidden' : 'visible'});
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaJBD/)

Incidentally, note I use visibility rather than literally hiding the button, because elements with `display: none` do not always have detectable positions.